# Raspberry Stucks After Welcome Screen

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, pi-3b+

My raspberry(pi 3B+) doesn't work after reboot. It stucks in black screen. The Red led is on but green one is first flashing then stops. And the point is flashing on screen.

Comment: You can't run Jessie on a Pi3B+

Comment: Was it working before the reboot? What did you change since last time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I Suggest that check your operating system compatibility with your raspberry pi version
If it was compatible, try to reinstall your OS